# insert query in vb2010 isn´t working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sqlite, insert

i have this query that works nice to insert data in aaccess db, but now im trying to insert on a sqllite3 db but im having trouble using the same query

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc

Public Class Form1
Public con As New OdbcConnection("Dsn=SQLite3 Datasource;database=C:\Users\pcampos\Desktop\spiceworks_prod.db;stepapi=0;syncpragma=NORMAL;notxn=0;timeout=100000;shortnames=0;longnames=0;nocreat=0;nowchar=0;fksupport=0;oemcp=0;bigint=0")

 Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO INSERT INTO tickets(id, summary, status)  VALUES(@id,@summary,@status )"


            con.Close()
            con.Open()
            Using cmd As New OdbcCommand(query, con)

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = test
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sumamry", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = "ola ola ola"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staus", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = "close"


                Dim x As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox(x)


                If x < 1 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Erro ao inserir", My.Application.Info.Title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Registo1 inserido com sucesso!", My.Application.Info.Title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

                End If
            End Using

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query is not valid SQL. It should be something like this:

```
 Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO tickets (id, summary, status) VALUES( @id, @summary, @status )"
```

See the [SQLite Insert Query Manual](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) for a diagram detailing the order of key words in an SQL Insert statement. The SQL would be an error on other SQL based systems, not just SQLite. Just thought I'd linke to that manual page as it is very useful.